# Issue with accessors in Drools

Tags: class, nested, drools, composite, accessor

I came across a particular scenario when updating composed objects in Drools:

```
declare A
    @propertyReactive
    flag: Boolean
end

declare B
    flag: Boolean
end

declare C
    @propertyReactive
    attrA: A
    attrB: B
end

rule "Create A"
    when
        not A()
    then
        insert(new A());
        System.out.println("OBJECT A CREATED");
end

rule "Create B"
    when
        not B()
    then
        insert(new B());
        System.out.println("OBJECT B CREATED");
end

rule "Create C"
    when
        $A:A()
        $B:B()
        not C()
    then
        insert(new C($A,$B));
        System.out.println("OBJECT C CREATED");
end

rule "Modify A"
    when
        $A:A(flag == false)
        C()
    then
        modify($A) {setFlag(true)};
        String $output = "Now A is " + $A.getFlag();
        System.out.println($output);
end

rule "Print C when C is False"
    when
        C($A:attrA, attrA.flag == false, $B:attrB)
    then
        String $output = "A is " + $A.getFlag() + " and B is " + $B.getFlag();
        System.out.println($output);
end 

rule "Print C when C is True"
    when
        C($A:attrA, attrA.flag == true, $B:attrB)
    then
        String $output = "A is " + $A.getFlag() + " and B is " + $B.getFlag();
        System.out.println($output);
end

rule "Print C when C is True 2"
    when
        C($A:attrA, $B:attrB)
        A(this == $A, flag == true)
    then
        String $output = "2 A is " + $A.getFlag() + " and B is " + $B.getFlag();
        System.out.println($output);
end
```

The output is:

```
OBJECT A CREATED
OBJECT B CREATED
OBJECT C CREATED
A is false and B is false
Now A is true
2 A is true and B is false
```

So I have the following questions:

- Why is rule "*Print C when C is True*" not firing?
- Why do I need to rewrite that rule as "*Print C when C is True 2*" to make it work?
- Does anybody have an explanation for this?

It looks like Drools has an issue in working with accessors of nested classes...

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Drools only reacts on changes performed to the objects used in your patterns and not to any nested object reference they may contain. And this is not entirely true either.

When you modify a fact in Drools (or any of its nested object references), you have the option to let Drools know about this modification or not. In your case, you are never notifying Drools about them. That is why your rules depend on the (not deterministic) evaluation order.

If you want to let Drools "know" about the modifications on a fact, then you must use the `modify` or `update` functions in the RHS of the rules where these modifications happen.

In your particular case, you have not only nested objects, but nested facts: `A` and `C`. Even if `A` is a fact, changes on `A` (even if properly notified to Drools) will never trigger the re-evaluation of a pattern like this:

```
C(attrA.flag == true)
```

The reason why is because the type of the pattern is `C` and not `A`. In these kind of scenarios, a rule written like your `Print C when C is True 2` rule is a better approach.

Hope it helps,